# How can I place an icon before Home and Notifications of the Drawer.Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am learning how to use React Navigation.

How can I place an icon before Home and Notifications of the Drawer.Screen

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And how do I do so that when entering the view add a tab screen

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component and render it in your drawer.

Here the ButtonList is a custom component that you pass it to drawerContent. And you can create a list in the ButtonList and put the icon between Home and Notification easily.

```
 <ActionDrawer.Navigator
      drawerType="back"
      drawerPosition="right"
      drawerContent={(props) => <ButtonList {...props} />}
      drawerStyle={{
        width: wp('65'),
      }}
    >
```